# How to fit small cubes into a given volume and represent it graphically on a web page?

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, linear-algebra

My query is to show programmatically, the fitting of many given non regular (but rectangular) cubes (i.e. boxes) of individually different sizes, inside a larger volume cube, such as a storage unit.

The mathematics part is understood. Like in Linear programming / linear algebra, we can add fit volume of all smaller cubes to find out the best fit for the volume of the larger cube.
The actual requirement is to show or allow this fitting graphically on a web-page, preferably in 3d. If possible, to allow user to interact with the fitting, i.e. shuffling the placement of the cubes, etc.

Also, since I am a Java developer by profession, Java or related languages / frameworks would be my choice. However, I can use any other technology / framework / language if the end results are met.

NB: Weight is also a concern (parameter). There is a maximum weight which can be stacked in any given storage unit.
Also, since storage units can be accessed without permission (by thieves), cost of the cubes stacked in one unit is also limited. The user may desire to fit cubes of higher cost in one unit which has higher security and vice versa.

Example: allow fitting many rectangular boxes containing household electronics in a given room. The boxes maybe of TVs, refrigerators, washing machines, dishwashers, playstations, xbox 360s, etc. The different dimensions of these boxes, is to give you an idea of what to expect while fitting to the limited volume.

If there is any FOSS library / project (or even non FOSS library or project) for the same, a pointer towards it would be welcome.

Comment: If you downvote, please comment with your reasons for doing so. I would then be able to rephrase, or provide better understanding. A simple downvote achieves nothing.

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but I have a few hints: (a) You mean cuboids, not cubes. (b) Usually SO questions are about programming problems, but you have not presented any code you have problems with. This kind of question may cause opinionated discussion instead of a concrete answer to a concrete question. (c) You say the mathematics are clear. So what are you looking for? Just the visualisation software? So it seems at first. But then you mention mathematical optimisation problems concerning weights and values, which represents a completely different problem.

Comment: @kriegaex: yes, mathematics are understood. and user interactive visualization is what I require. By mentioning the optimization issues, I only wanted to inform any reader about the constraints that will need to be considered, by me, not them.

Comment: I am a visualisation noob and usually prefer back-end stuff. Thus, I do not know the 3D library market. But what I just found in my old code base was code from 2006 using Java 3D. It also visualises cuboids in a larger box as part of a solution of a programming challenge taken from "Bundeswettbewerb Informatik 2004", a national informatics challenge for teenage kids. I did it just for fun and even I as a noob found Java 3D pretty easy to use. There is no interactivity or animation, but that you could build by yourself.

Comment: The programming challenge (in German, unfortunately) is "Aufgabe 3" from http://www.bwinf.de/uploads/media/bwi23/runde1/bwinf231.pdf. If you want to see my solution (just 3 fairly simple classes encompassing the algorithm from the callenge and the visualisation of the solution), tell me and I can push it to GitHub or just copy & paste the classes here.

Comment: Any guidance on the same is welcome. Please provide me with the classes you speak of, in any way you deem fit.

Answer (score 4):

***Disclaimer:*** Okay, I know it does not 100% answer your question and also the code it veeery old (as can be concluded from the old-fashioned CVS comments) and today I would not write it that way anymore. It does still run on Java 8, though, I tested it. But in addition to solving the little informatics challenge problem of water flowing through a 3D matrix of cuboids from top to bottom depending how "leaky" the matrix (symbolising some kind of Swiss cheese) is, it also uses some very simple 3D visualisation via Java 3D. Thus, you need to install Java 3D and put the corresponding libraries onto your classpath.

The 3D output looks something like this:

[image: Leaky cheese]

```java
package vhs.bwinfo.cheese;

// $Id: Cuboid.java,v 1.1.2.1 2006/01/10 19:48:41 Robin Exp $

import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.QuadArray;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.vecmath.Point3f;
import javax.vecmath.TexCoord2f;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

public class Cuboid extends Shape3D {
  private static final float POS = +0.5f;
  private static final float NEG = -0.5f;
  private static final Point3f[] POINTS = new Point3f[] {
    new Point3f(NEG, NEG, NEG),
    new Point3f(POS, NEG, NEG),
    new Point3f(POS, NEG, POS),
    new Point3f(NEG, NEG, POS),
    new Point3f(NEG, POS, NEG),
    new Point3f(POS, POS, NEG),
    new Point3f(POS, POS, POS),
    new Point3f(NEG, POS, POS)
  };
  private static final TexCoord2f[] TEX_COORDS = new TexCoord2f[] {
    new TexCoord2f(0, 1),
    new TexCoord2f(1, 1),
    new TexCoord2f(1, 0),
    new TexCoord2f(0, 0)
  };
  private static final int VERTEX_FORMAT =
    QuadArray.COORDINATES |
      QuadArray.NORMALS |
      QuadArray.TEXTURE_COORDINATE_2;

  public Cuboid(float scaleX, float scaleY, float scaleZ) {
    Point3f[] points = new Point3f[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      points[i] = new Point3f(
        POINTS[i].x * scaleX,
        POINTS[i].y * scaleY,
        POINTS[i].z * scaleZ
      );

    Point3f[] vertices = {
      points[3], points[2], points[1], points[0],  // bottom
      points[4], points[5], points[6], points[7],  // top
      points[7], points[3], points[0], points[4],  // left
      points[6], points[5], points[1], points[2],  // right
      points[7], points[6], points[2], points[3],  // front
      points[5], points[4], points[0], points[1]    // back
    };

    QuadArray geometry = new QuadArray(24, VERTEX_FORMAT);
    geometry.setCoordinates(0, vertices);
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
      geometry.setTextureCoordinate(0, i, TEX_COORDS[i % 4]);

    Vector3f normal = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v1 = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f v2 = new Vector3f();
    Point3f[] pts = new Point3f[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      pts[i] = new Point3f();

    for (int face = 0; face < 6; face++) {
      geometry.getCoordinates(face * 4, pts);
      v1.sub(pts[0], pts[2]);
      v2.sub(pts[1], pts[3]);
      normal.cross(v1, v2);
      normal.normalize();
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        geometry.setNormal((face * 4 + i), normal);
    }
    setGeometry(geometry);
    setAppearance(new Appearance());
  }

  public Cuboid(float scaleFactor) {
    this(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
  }
}
```

```java
package vhs.bwinfo.cheese;

// $Id: LeakyCheese.java,v 1.2.2.2 2006/01/10 15:37:14 Robin Exp $

import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.JMainFrame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class LeakyCheese {
  private int width = 20, height = 20, depth = 20;
  private int numClasses = 100, samplesPerClass = 100;
  private double pMin = 0, pMax = 1;
  private double pDiff = pMax - pMin;
  private double classSize = pDiff / numClasses;
  private int[] stats;

  enum CubeState {CHEESE, AIR, WATER}

  final private CubeState[][][] cheese;

  private static final Random RND = new Random();

  public LeakyCheese(
    int width, int height, int depth,
    int numClasses, int samplesPerClass,
    double pMin, double pMax
  ) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.depth = depth;
    this.numClasses = numClasses;
    this.samplesPerClass = samplesPerClass;
    this.pMin = pMin;
    this.pMax = pMax;
    pDiff = pMax - pMin;
    classSize = pDiff / numClasses;
    cheese = new CubeState[width][height][depth];
  }

  public LeakyCheese(
    int width, int height, int depth,
    int numClasses, int samplesPerClass
  ) {
    this(width, height, depth, numClasses, samplesPerClass, 0, 1);
  }

  public LeakyCheese() {
    cheese = new CubeState[width][height][depth];
  }

  private boolean pourWater(int x, int y, int z) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height || z < 0 || z >= depth)
      return false;
    if (cheese[x][y][z] != CubeState.AIR)
      return false;
    cheese[x][y][z] = CubeState.WATER;
    boolean retVal = (y == 0);
    retVal = pourWater(x + 1, y, z) || retVal;
    retVal = pourWater(x - 1, y, z) || retVal;
    retVal = pourWater(x, y + 1, z) || retVal;
    retVal = pourWater(x, y - 1, z) || retVal;
    retVal = pourWater(x, y, z + 1) || retVal;
    retVal = pourWater(x, y, z - 1) || retVal;
    return retVal;
  }

  private boolean isLeaky(double p) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
          cheese[x][y][z] = (RND.nextDouble() < p)
            ? CubeState.CHEESE
            : CubeState.AIR;
    boolean retVal = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
      for (int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
        retVal = pourWater(x, height - 1, z) || retVal;
    return retVal;
  }

  private void generateStats() {
    if (stats != null)
      return;
    stats = new int[numClasses];
    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < samplesPerClass; j++) {
        double p = pMin + classSize * (RND.nextDouble() + i);
        if (isLeaky(p))
          stats[i]++;
      }
    }
  }

  public void printStats() {
    generateStats();
    out.println(
      "p (cheese)        |  p (leaky)\n" +
        "------------------+-----------"
    );
    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
      out.println(
        String.format(
          "%1.5f..%1.5f  |  %1.5f",
          pMin + classSize * i,
          pMin + classSize * (i + 1),
          (double) stats[i] / samplesPerClass
        )
      );
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //new LeakyCheese().printStats();
    //new LeakyCheese(40, 40, 40, 50, 100, 0.66, .71).printStats();

    LeakyCheese cheeseBlock = new LeakyCheese(5, 20, 5, 20, 100);
    //LeakyCheese cheeseBlock = new LeakyCheese(20, 20, 20, 20, 100);
    while (!cheeseBlock.isLeaky(0.65))
      ;
    out.println("*** required solution found - now rendering... ***");
    JMainFrame f = new JMainFrame(new LeakyCheeseGUI(cheeseBlock.cheese), 512, 512);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
  }
}
```

```java
package vhs.bwinfo.cheese;

// $Id: LeakyCheeseGUI.java,v 1.1.2.1 2006/01/10 15:25:18 Robin Exp $

import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import vhs.bwinfo.cheese.LeakyCheese.CubeState;

import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class LeakyCheeseGUI extends Applet {
  static final long serialVersionUID = -8194627556699837928L;

  public BranchGroup createSceneGraph(CubeState[][][] cheese) {
    // Create the root of the branch graph
    BranchGroup bgRoot = new BranchGroup();

    // Composite of two rotations around different axes. The resulting
    // TransformGroup is the parent of all our cheese cubes, because their
    // orientation is identical. They only differ in their translation
    // values and colours.
    Transform3D tRotate = new Transform3D();
    Transform3D tRotateTemp = new Transform3D();
    tRotate.rotX(Math.PI / 8.0d);
    tRotateTemp.rotY(Math.PI / -4.0d);
    tRotate.mul(tRotateTemp);
    TransformGroup tgRotate = new TransformGroup(tRotate);
    bgRoot.addChild(tgRotate);

    // Bounding sphere for rendering
    BoundingSphere bounds =
      new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 100.0);

    // Set background colour
    // Note: Using Canvas3D.setBackground does not work, because it is an
    // AWT method. Java 3D, though, gets its background colour from its
    // background node (black, if not present).
    Background background = new Background(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    background.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
    bgRoot.addChild(background);

    TransparencyAttributes transpAttr;

    // Little cheese cubes
    Appearance cheeseAppearance = new Appearance();
    transpAttr =
      new TransparencyAttributes(TransparencyAttributes.NICEST, 0.98f);
    cheeseAppearance.setTransparencyAttributes(transpAttr);
    cheeseAppearance.setColoringAttributes(
      new ColoringAttributes(1, 1, 0, ColoringAttributes.NICEST));
    PolygonAttributes pa = new PolygonAttributes();
    //pa.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
    pa.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
    cheeseAppearance.setPolygonAttributes(pa);

    // Little water cubes
    Appearance waterAppearance = new Appearance();
    transpAttr =
      new TransparencyAttributes(TransparencyAttributes.NICEST, 0.85f);
    waterAppearance.setTransparencyAttributes(transpAttr);
    waterAppearance.setColoringAttributes(
      new ColoringAttributes(0, 0, 1, ColoringAttributes.NICEST));
    pa = new PolygonAttributes();
    pa.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
    waterAppearance.setPolygonAttributes(pa);

    // Little air cubes
    Appearance airAppearance = new Appearance();
    transpAttr =
      new TransparencyAttributes(TransparencyAttributes.NICEST, 0.95f);
    airAppearance.setTransparencyAttributes(transpAttr);
    airAppearance.setColoringAttributes(
      new ColoringAttributes(1, 1, 1, ColoringAttributes.NICEST));
    pa = new PolygonAttributes();
    //pa.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
    pa.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
    airAppearance.setPolygonAttributes(pa);

    // Water-coloured (i.e. blue) wire frame around cheese block, if leaky
    Appearance waterWireFrameAppearance = new Appearance();
    waterWireFrameAppearance.setColoringAttributes(
      new ColoringAttributes(0, 0, 1, ColoringAttributes.NICEST));
    pa = new PolygonAttributes();
    pa.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
    pa.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
    waterWireFrameAppearance.setPolygonAttributes(pa);

    // Cheese-coloured (i.e. yellow) wire frame around cheese block, if not leaky
    Appearance cheeseWireFrameAppearance = new Appearance();
    cheeseWireFrameAppearance.setColoringAttributes(
      new ColoringAttributes(1, 1, 0, ColoringAttributes.NICEST));
    pa = new PolygonAttributes();
    pa.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
    pa.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
    cheeseWireFrameAppearance.setPolygonAttributes(pa);

    // Absolute offsets for the cheese block to fit into the viewing canvas
    final float xOffs = -0.8f;
    final float yOffs = -0.55f;
    final float zOffs = 0;

    // Create all those little cubes ;-)
    final int xSize = cheese.length;
    final int ySize = cheese[0].length;
    final int zSize = cheese[0][0].length;
    final int maxSize = Math.max(xSize, Math.max(ySize, zSize));
    final float xCenterOffs = 0.5f * (maxSize - xSize) / maxSize;
    final float yCenterOffs = 0.5f * (maxSize - ySize) / maxSize;
    final float zCenterOffs = -0.5f * (maxSize - zSize) / maxSize;
    boolean isLeaky = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
      for (int y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++) {
          Transform3D tTranslate = new Transform3D();
          tTranslate.setTranslation(
            new Vector3f(
              xOffs + xCenterOffs + 1.0f * x / maxSize,
              yOffs + yCenterOffs + 1.0f * y / maxSize,
              zOffs + zCenterOffs - 1.0f * z / maxSize
            )
          );
          TransformGroup tgTranslate = new TransformGroup(tTranslate);
          tgRotate.addChild(tgTranslate);
          Cuboid cube = new Cuboid(1.0f / maxSize);
          switch (cheese[x][y][z]) {
            case CHEESE:
              cube.setAppearance(cheeseAppearance);
              break;
            case WATER:
              cube.setAppearance(waterAppearance);
              if (y == 0)
                isLeaky = true;
              break;
            case AIR:
              cube.setAppearance(airAppearance);
          }
          tgTranslate.addChild(cube);
        }

    // If cheese block is leaky, visualise it by drawing a water-coloured
    // (i.e. blue) wire frame around it. Otherwise use a cheese-coloured
    // (i.e. yellow) one.
    Transform3D tTranslate = new Transform3D();
    tTranslate.setTranslation(
      new Vector3f(
        xOffs + xCenterOffs + 0.5f * (xSize - 1) / maxSize,
        yOffs + yCenterOffs + 0.5f * (ySize - 1) / maxSize,
        zOffs + zCenterOffs - 0.5f * (zSize - 1) / maxSize
      )
    );
    TransformGroup tgTranslate = new TransformGroup(tTranslate);
    tgRotate.addChild(tgTranslate);
    Cuboid cuboid = new Cuboid(
      1.0f * xSize / maxSize,
      1.0f * ySize / maxSize,
      1.0f * zSize / maxSize
    );
    cuboid.setAppearance(isLeaky ? waterWireFrameAppearance : cheeseWireFrameAppearance);
    tgTranslate.addChild(cuboid);

    // Let Java 3D perform optimizations on this scene graph.
    bgRoot.compile();

    return bgRoot;
  }

  public LeakyCheeseGUI(CubeState[][][] cheese) {
    // Create a simple scene and attach it to the virtual universe
    GraphicsConfiguration graphCfg = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
    Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(graphCfg);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(canvas, "Center");
    SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);

    // This will move the ViewPlatform back a bit so the objects
    // in the scene can be viewed.
    universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
    universe.addBranchGraph(createSceneGraph(cheese));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Random RND = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    CubeState[][][] testCheese = new CubeState[5][8][11];
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
      for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        for (int z = 0; z < 11; z++)
          testCheese[x][y][z] = (RND.nextFloat() < 0.7f)
            ? CubeState.CHEESE
            : (RND.nextBoolean() ? CubeState.WATER : CubeState.AIR);
    // Applet can also run as a stand-alone application
    new MainFrame(new LeakyCheeseGUI(testCheese), 512, 512);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You will probably want to use Javascript, and specifically WebGL. Javascript is the de facto language for interactive web pages, and [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) is a Javascript API for rendering 2D and 3D scenes on an HTML5 canvas element. A solution using WebGL should be compatible with all major browsers. Programming even simple scenes in WebGL can be pretty involved though, so I'd recommend using a framework such as [three.js](https://threejs.org/) to simplify things.

[Here](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes) is an example of interactive, draggable cubes using three.js. Some of the key lines of code from that example are:

```
// create the cube 
var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

// set coordinates, rotation, and scale of the cubes
object.position.x = ...
object.position.y = ...
object.position.z = ...
object.rotation.x = ...
object.rotation.y = ...
object.rotation.z = ...
object.scale.x = ...
object.scale.y = ...
object.scale.z = ...

// lighting stuff
object.castShadow = true;
object.receiveShadow = true;

// add to scene and list of objects
scene.add( object );
objects.push( object );
```

Again, the full, working example is found [at this link](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cube#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes) (click [view source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html) on that page to view the code on github).

Comment: The question is tagged `java`, not `javascript`. Thus, your answer is pretty much irrelevant. Nobody said the visualisation should be in a web browser. The OP even wrote that he prefers Java ecosystem solutions.

Comment: kriegaex, you are incorrect. OP said in his question that he wants to "represent it graphically on a web page", and that he wants the user to be able to interact with it. He also said "Java or related languages / frameworks ... I can use any other technology / framework / language if the end results are met." Web pages are ONLY viewed in web browsers, and running Java in web pages is rarely done anymore, if at all. I presented him with a similar language and a framework, as he requested.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately I overlooked that. So please accept my apology. I concentrated on his statements about Java and the question tags. Do you also have some sample code for the frameworks mentioned?

Comment: No problem. I think our answers complement each other, since there's a decent chance he said web page but just meant any interactive java application, or maybe he does really want to make java code run in-browser, which I wouldn't recommend but I think it can still be done if one really, really wants to make it work.

Comment: This solution looks better, let me try that out.